# Problems upgrading to Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm trying to upgrade a project to Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0 and I'm facing two problems :

1. The "spring-data-neo4j-rest" package is missing at MvnRepository ([spring-data-neo4j-rest-4.0.0.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-neo4j-rest/4.0.0.RELEASE) returns 404 error). Does the package still exist and should be there, or should I just delete the dependency from my pom.xml?
2. I've got the following error : `The method fetch(Set<...>) is undefined for the type Neo4jOperations` in all my DAOs. The method was used to initialize collections of lazily loaded nodes. How can I initialize a node's collections?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the migration guide that's provided for SDN 4?

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#migration

fetch is gone and replaced by fetch-depth 
SDN-rest is gone too any not needed anymore (as SDN-4 is all about remote connections).